# Unable to run cassandra cluster on mesos cluster on marathon framework

Tags: cassandra, mesos, marathon

I am able to start the mesos cluster and marathon framework and ran a demo application which prints hello. I am successfully able to do this on a ec2 instance.

Now I started a cassandra cluster on a different ec2 instance and it started successfully but I was not able to deploy the cassandra cluster on mesos cluster using marathon framework.

This is my code:

```
{
  "id": "/cassandra/dev-test",
  "instances": 1,
  "cpus" : 0.5   ,
  "mem": 512,
  "ports": [
    0
  ],
  "uris": [
    "https://downloads.mesosphere.io/cassandra-mesos/artifacts/0.2.0-1/cassandra-mesos-0.2.0-1.tar.gz",
    "https://downloads.mesosphere.io/java/jre-7u76-linux-x64.tar.gz"
  ],
  "env": {
    "MESOS_ZK": "zk://34.201.141.21:2181/mesos",
    "JAVA_OPTS": "-Xms256m -Xmx256m",
    "CASSANDRA_CLUSTER_NAME": "dev-test",
    "CASSANDRA_ZK": "zk://34.201.141.21:2181/cassandra-mesos",
    "CASSANDRA_NODE_COUNT": "3",
    "CASSANDRA_SEED_COUNT": "2",
    "CASSANDRA_SEEDS": "54.187.196.55,34.220.73.46 ",
    "CASSANDRA_RESOURCE_CPU_CORES": "2.0",
    "CASSANDRA_RESOURCE_MEM_MB": "2048",
    "CASSANDRA_RESOURCE_DISK_MB": "2048",
    "CASSANDRA_HEALTH_CHECK_INTERVAL_SECONDS": "60",
    "CASSANDRA_FAILOVER_TIMEOUT_SECONDS": "604800",
    "CASSANDRA_BOOTSTRAP_GRACE_TIME_SECONDS": "120",
    "CASSANDRA_ZK_TIMEOUT_MS": "10000"
  },
  "cmd": "$(pwd)/jre*/bin/java $JAVA_OPTS -classpath cassandra-mesos-framework.jar io.mesosphere.mesos.frameworks.cassandra.framework.Main",
  "healthChecks": [
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 0,
      "path": "/health/cluster",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    },
    {
      "gracePeriodSeconds": 120,
      "intervalSeconds": 30,
      "maxConsecutiveFailures": 3,
      "path": "/health/process",
      "portIndex": 0,
      "protocol": "HTTP",
      "timeoutSeconds": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the code 
The log file is very big so I am not able to attach it here.

The other way I used is through Vagrant but I am unable to create Mesos cluster through it.
Link is given below :
https://github.com/jonasrosland/vagrant-mesos

Thanks for the help in advance !!!

Comment: Please add logs, and other information to your question - otherwise it's very unclear...

Comment: I am trying to run Cassandra-cluster on Mesos so I found a solution to create Mesos cluster using Vagrant.

I tried running Mesos cluster using Vagrant.

I installed Vagrant version 2.1.2 and all its plugins:

vagrant-aws (0.7.2)
vagrant-berkshelf (5.1.2)
vagrant-cachier (1.2.1)
vagrant-hosts (2.8.2)
vagrant-omnibus (1.5.0)
I also made changes in AWS credentials in the following file

 access_key_id:  EDIT_HERE
 secret_access_key: EDIT_HERE
  [

 region: us-east-1

 security_groups: EDIT_HERE

 instance_type: m1.small
This is what I tried , but I am open to other methods.

Comment: Please put this information into your question, including the logs from Mesos, etc.

Comment: I have edited the Question

Comment: Try making **instances** be equal with **Cassandra seeds count**?